# Search API, how to like query

Tags: google-app-engine, full-text-search, gae-search

I'm using the Search API GAE, how to make a query like "like%"? as is done in SQL example:
select * from person where name like '% john%';

Comment: what do you want exactly please explain it .

Comment: I want to do a search using the search service (Search API) like this in SQL:
select * from name like '% jo%'; (return john)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your queryString would be "name: john" on the person index with name field set to be a Text field.

A regular query with ':' or '=' on the Text or HTML type of index value is closest (not same) to 'like' in SQL.

Details on available operators to use in the query are at
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/search/query_strings#Java_Queries_on_text_and_HTML_fields.

Also check stemming if your use-case is to find words with similar meaning.
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/search/query_strings#Java_Stemming

Comment: thank you, I'm Brazilian I'm using google translator.But if your putting "name: jo" (similar to "like '%jo%' ") returns no data

Comment: Joander, I don't think "like '%jo%'" kind of queries are supported in GAE-search yet, you may raise a ticket to add it though. Or else you can go to your database for these. GAE-search is primarily designed to work on the context and it uses tokens (whole words). What you can do though is stemming, if your use-case is to find words with similar meaning.
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/search/query_strings#Java_Stemming